# How does this answer really answer the question?

Tags: discussion, answers

[Views not updating?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/views-not-updating/6502#6502)

The answer seems to better suit a comment:

- It points to a forum post that, as admitted from the OP, doesn't report any solution for the issue
- It suggests opening an issue report on drupal.org

If the user who asked the question should open an issue on drupal.org, then the question should be probably be closed. Still, I don't understand how the answer is really answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, really.

It looks like the poster may have chosen that answer because they figured out their problem. Maybe they think it functions as a "Case Closed" or "I don't need any more help, I've got it".

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that

> Check the filters

Lead the question asked to where he had misconfigured the view.

As he commented:

> Actually, I figured it out now. It WAS something in the views- I had a flag set- where the flag was required to be checked. Grrr.... it works great now! Thanks!

It seems like *he/she*  got something out of the post, which could be why he marked it with accepted answer.

Comment: Actually it is "Check the filters?" which would be  understood as "Did you check the filters?" The fact a post that should have been a comment has been accepted as answer doesn't mean the post is an answer. I wonder what somebody else with the same problem would understand from that answer.